# PC Pentium 4 on an HP pavilion. Any help?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have tied 3 different versions and they install but won't start.... I get the log in screen then it starts having problems. I have a PC Pentium 4 on an HP pavilion.
Any help?

Comment: Have you checked your hardware such as running a sector scan on your HDD and memtestx86 on your ram? If you have tried 3 different distro's then I would do a quick check on your hardware as well...

Comment: Edit your question to tell us what kind of problems you get.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but the lightest version of Ubuntu is Lubuntu which uses LXDE desktop. I have installed it in some PIV without problems. I think that lastest version of Lubuntu, (13.04) is the most suitable as that Linux is designed for old PCs too.